# Angular not displaying data from component.ts to html

Tags: typescript, angular7

I'm trying to display the offices to a dropdown select element. I've checked/validated that my api is returning the correct data. However in my angular component (ts and html) file, I was not able to display it.

model file

```
export interface Office {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  sections: Array<Sections>;
}

export interface Sections {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  code: string;
}
```

service file

```
getOffices() {
  return this.http.get<{offices: Office[]}>(`${BACKEND_URL}`);
}
```

component file

```
offices: Office[] = [];

constructor(public officesService: OfficesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    return this.officesService.getOffices().subscribe((officesData: {offices: Office[]}) => {
      this.offices = officesData.offices;
    });

  }

//at this point I can see from my browser Network tab the offices preview and the data are correct
```

html file

```
<mat-select name="office" placeholder="Office" #officeInput="ngModel" matInput ngModel required>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let office of offices" value="">{{ office.name }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your component has change detection set to `OnPush`, you need to manually trigger change detection when data changes without inputs changing:

```
offices: Office[] = [];

constructor(public officesService: OfficesService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit() {

  return this.officesService.getOffices().subscribe((officesData: {offices: Office[]}) => {
    this.offices = officesData.offices;
    this.cd.markForCheck();
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to reach data that is not exist.

in the service you are expecting to get the offices -> 
`return this.http.get<{offices: Office[]}>(`${BACKEND_URL}`);`

But in the component you are trying to get `(officesData: {offices: Office[]})`

Try this -

`this.officesService.getOffices().subscribe((offices: Office[]) => this.offices = offices);`